# Can we exclude Web Application's PublishProfies folder from project and source control in VS 2012?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-application-project

With the new Visual Studio 2012 there is this so called directory "PublishProfies" which is located under the "Properties" folder.

Every time we create a publish profile for a web application, it is stored into that directory, then automatically added to the project and the source control (we are using TFS 2012). For our development environment this is not a desired behaviour. We would like each developer's machine to be able to have it's own publish profiles.

Is it possible to somehow tell the Visual Studio to store these profiles elsewhere, or at least not to add them to the project structure and source control respectfully?

Comment: Seems like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369442/how-can-i-exclude-a-specific-files-from-tfs-source-control

Comment: @allen nope. Excluding the folder, doesn't change a thing, it's still included into the solution, which is under source control, and that defeats the purpose. I want the publishprofiles folder to not be located under the project at all.