# Do I want to include the Azure csx folder in configuration control?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs

My MVC 4 app is deployed to Azure.  The Azure project includes a csx folder.  Is there anything in that folder that doesn't get automatically recreated when I publish to Azure?  In other words, is there anything in that folder that qualifies as "source code" that I should add to my version control system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The csx folder can be excluded from source control. Note that if you pull a .gitingore file from gitignore.io it will exclude this automatically.

http://gitignore.io/api/visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the **Azure Build Output** `csx` folder by using the below [`.tfignore` in your Azure project or solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16158098/175679) if you are using TFS 2012+.

You can also [generate a`.tfignore` file from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore) using Team Explorer **Pending Changes** view *Excluded Changes->Detected->Right-Click File->Ignore Options*. Then you can manually edit it as needed.

[image]

#### .tfignore (*File Contents - [save using Notepad to your solution/project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004633)*)

```
################################################################################

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef
```