# Ignore Items in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm trying to do an initial code check-in with Team Foundation Server through Visual Studio. After trying to check in once, I got a few errors back. These errors were on ReSharper files. Since I don't need to check these in, obviously, I am now trying to exclude them. But I can't seem to get them out of my pending changes without doing "Undo Pending Changes" on each ReSharper folder. Since there is a number of these, and I'd probably have to do it on every check-in, I was hoping there was an easier way to ignore these files going forward (similar to git's ignoring features).

How can I ignore all of these ReSharper folders and files within them for all future check-ins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I exclude a specific files from TFS source control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369442/how-can-i-exclude-a-specific-files-from-tfs-source-control)

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [How can I exclude a specific file from TFS source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369442/how-can-i-exclude-a-specific-files-from-tfs-source-control)

Assuming you are also on TFS 2012, you might want to check out the [`.tfignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore) file. Similar to a `.gitignore` file, you can specify file and folder patterns to ignore.

**Edit** to answer question in comment:

You can create this file yourself (just a text file named `.tfignore`), and place it in any directory where you want the rules to apply. The rules are applied recursively to subdirectories, but you can place additional `.tfignore` files in subdirectories to have more fine grained control.

An additional hint for creating the file in Windows Explorer: right-click and choose New > Text File. Name the file **`.tfignore.`** (notice the *trailing* dot). The trailing dot is automatically removed and you end up with the correct file name.

Comment: Where is this file located?