# Prevent check-in of generated CSS from LESS file in TFS

Tags: tfs, less, web-essentials

We use Web Essentials in our Visual Studio project, and we use a main Site.Less file that compiles into Site.css, and Site.css.map & Site.min.css.

Because Less is a new technology to some team members we sometimes get people writing code into the Site.css file and checking that in. Recently we had a week's worth of changes that got overwritten because somebody else changed the Less file, compiled and checked in. Thankfully the history kept the .css changes.

Is there a way to prevent the Site.css file, which is underneath Site.less, from being checked in? This would serve as a reminder that people need to edit the Less file and not the CSS file.

Comment: I hope (and it seems so) that you're using a versioning system. If you use for example Git, you can set `.gitignore` to prevent that Git watches for edits in `Site.css`. Obviously, doing this, processed file must be generated during deploy on webserver due to fact that is no longer versioned (and so updated)

Comment: It is Team Foundation Server we are using. I've used git in the past and I was hoping TFS had an ignore file, but I cannot right-click and choose to exclude the Site.css as per other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Foundation Server version control (TFVC) supports a `.tfignore` file if you're using local workspaces. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx) for more information on the format of `.tfignore`

Comment: Thanks. i can create this file, add it to source control and when the team member does a Get Latest, they'll have it.

Answer (score 1):

**Git** has `.gitignore` to prevent watching for edits in `Site.css`.

If you're using **Team Foundation Server**, please, see this [old similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369442/how-can-i-exclude-a-specific-file-from-tfs-source-control). Accepted answer is another one, but in my opinion [this is answer you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26055218/2384685).

In short:

1. File -> Source Control -> Advanced
2. Select "Exclude < *filename* > from Source Control"

Look at the link to further details.

Comment: Like other people on that question, I don't have that option unfortunately.