# Forbidden Patterns Check-In Policy in TFS 2010

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I've been trying to use the Forbidden Patterns part of the TFS 2010 Power Tools and I'm just not understanding something - I simply cannot get anything to change as I try to use this! I'm using the version that was released recently (I believe April 23, 2010), so it's not an old version.

First off, yes, I know it's regex based, so let's clear that doubt...

I have tried to block the following scenarios:

1)
I have modified all of my T4 EF templates to generate files named `EntityName.gen.cs`. I then attempted to prevent TFS from wanting to check those files in. I used the regular expression `\.gen\.cs\z` and it didn't change a single thing! I even tried it without the `\z` and nadda!

2)
I don't want app.config and web.config files to be checked-in by default because we have these things stored into app.config.base and web.config.base files that our build scripts use to generate our per-environment app.config and web.config files. As such, I tried the following regexes and again, nothing worked! `web\.config\z`, `app\.config\z`, `web\.release\.config\z` and `web\.debug\.config\z`.

What is it that I am screwing up with this?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a set of expressions we use that work.  We have the [December 2011 Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) installed, which is where the Forbidden Patterns Policy feature comes from, not from a base TFS 2010 install.

`.*/[Bb]in/.*`

`.*/[Pp]ackages/.*`

`.*/[Oo]bj/.*`

`.*/_[Rr]eshar[Pp]er./.*`

`\.((?i)suo$)`

`\.((?i)user$)`

`thumbs\.db`

I also found [another site](http://www.havecomputerwillcode.com/blog/?p=297) that has a good write-up with example patterns.

Answer (score 3):

After playing around for a while I found a working solution for excluding *.config files (derived from the following blog [link text](http://kevinhick.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/forbidden-patterns-policy-example/))

`^(.+\.config$)`

Please don't ask me why it's the way it is, I don't really get it myself, especially the part with '$)' (')$' does not work!)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've created one for future use and test it online https://regex101.com/r/xK0jS9/1