# Preventing TFS from adding Temporary files

Tags: c#, asp.net, version-control, tfs

I am working on a Project that is bind in TFS, this project gives me a folder Log.

When I execute my project and do some testing it generates text files and store in Log folder.

After that when I try to check in files those files are checked in as a new file in TFS.

I want TFS to exclude these files.  Folders where I store temp files are:

1. `\WebPages\ErrorLogs`
2. `\WebPages\TempReports`

Is there a setting in TFS where I can say it not to include this folder in TFS but Get latest from server if any?

Is it possible to create a Check-in-Policy for this problem?

Comment: If it is project item you just can open projectname.csproj.vspcss file and write number of files to exclude and links to them. "NUMBER_OF_EXCLUDED_FILES" = "1"
"EXCLUDED_FILE0" = "web.config"

Comment: Use [Cloaking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9742947/147211)

Comment: The folder is from TFS but the files are generated at local system. Maximum Number of files is unlimited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forbidden Patterns Check-In Policy in TFS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741412/forbidden-patterns-check-in-policy-in-tfs-2010)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the **Forbidden Patterns Policy** included in the [**TFS Power Tools**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/)

The following regex prevents `suo` files from being checked-in:

```
\.((?i)suo$)
```

The following regex prevents `bin`, `obj` and `debug` folders from being checked-in:

```
^\\(bin)|(obj)|(debug)\\$
```

Comment: can you provide a regex that excludes all files from one fixed location (folder)

Comment: my temp files are stored in WebPages\ErrorLogs and WebPages\TempReports folder. as per your answer is this right:   ^\\((WebPages)\(ErrorLogs))|((WebPages)\(TempReports))\$

Comment: This should do: `/(ErrorLogs)|(TempReports)/*`

Comment: What about the WebPages folder, don't you think this should be consider in expression?

Comment: I suppose you can prefix it, but it's not a must unless you have multiple ErrorLogs or TempReports folders

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Team Explorer Everywhere you can [use this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to find out how to configure the policies directly through the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Eclipse. I use Visual Studio.