# Exclude files from TFS via project file

Tags: file, tfs, project

I am searching for a possibility to exclude some files of my generated VS project file from TFS. I know that it is possibly afterwards with the .vspscc file.

But what i want is, that i can tell the VS project file, that some of it's files are not allowed to get added to TFS, before I add the project to TFS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several levels of excluding files in TFS:

1. Manually by excluding a file or folder on the check-in dialog.
2. Manually by excluding a file or folder on the `Add items to Folder` dialog.
   [image: tfs scm exclude manually]
3. On the `Add items to Folder` dialog > `Automatically exclude from source control`:
   [image: tfs exclude]
   *Note*: the default items can be [modified using the registry](http://blog.accentient.com/2011/04/14/ExcludingFoldersAndFilesWhenAddingToSourceControl.aspx).
4. On the team project source control level using a [**check-in policy**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749057/147211).
5. On the source control permissions level:
   `Source Control` > Mark a folder > `Security` > Deny Check-In permission
   [image: tfs scm permissions]
6. On the workspace level by **[cloaking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742947/147211)**.

Comment: Okay maybe if have to explain a bit more. I have a tool, which generates a complete solution (I have to change this tool). This solution is added to TFS. But when adding, these specific files should not be added. So is there a way to mark this files before adding to TFS.

Comment: Does the solution is being generated with a script or some blackboxed application? Does it being added to TFS automatically or by the user?

Comment: See updated answer. In this case I think options 1-3 applies for you.

Comment: Let me not agree with KMoraz. I would first explore extending the tool to perform some of the tfs operations - make it pend add on the correct files or update workspace with cloaks. I would recommend first approach

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the accepted answer by KMoraz.  #1 and #2 don't seem to be permanent, #3 doesn't even appear for me (I'm using VS2012), #4 and #5 require permissions (which I don't have on CodePlex) and #6 is not even relevant (because you cannot cloak something that isn't first checked-in).

I know your question is about BEFORE they are added, but I think the answer, which is to create a ".tfignore" file, only works for TFS 2012.

For me I had to locate the ".vspscc" file (which I know you already stated) in the project folder and look for this line:

```
"NUMBER_OF_EXCLUDED_FILES" = "0"
```

In my case I wanted to exclude TypeScript generated files, so I added this:

```
"NUMBER_OF_EXCLUDED_FILES" = "3"
"EXCLUDED_FILE0" = "app.js"
"EXCLUDED_FILE1" = "app.js.map"
"EXCLUDED_FILE2" = "app.min.js"
```

I really hope they get their head on straight and add the feature you're looking for to VS in a more accessible way.

... and yes, there's a menu for excluding files in "File->Source Control->Advanced", but it should be in a context menu, and it doesn't apply to NESTED files (such as the app.* ones above [for .ts files]).

Comment: Worst yet, it's not even working for me. I've excluded the file from source control as described, but any changes to that file cause it to reappear in "Pending Changes"