# Visual Studio 2012 - Adding files via Solution Explorer not showing in Pending Changes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, projects-and-solutions, solution-explorer, source-control-explorer

I have a VS 2012 solution with multiple projects in it.

When I create a new solution folder or new a folder under projects and add files via the "Solution Explorer" it just modifies the `sln` or `csproj` file. The newly added files do not show up in "Pending Changes".

I am having to add the files explicitly again via "Source Control Explorer" -> "Add Items to Folder" to have it actually `[add]` before check-in.

What would I need to change to have the files added via "Solution Explorer" itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a brand new solution, and then add it to source control. Does the issue still happen for new projects in that solution? Is it the same behaviour for your colleagues?

If so then it sounds to me like you have some strange checkin policy screwing it up.

See the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698407/exclude-files-from-tfs-via-project-file) for ideas.

Failing all of those, maybe a reinstall of TFS on the server is required, or if it's only affecting you, reinstall VS.