# Using TFS source control - how to remove files

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am a lone developer, and I am now using TFS 2010, having until recently used VSS.
I have not found it easy to get any books for beginners to help me use this.
So I have now got my project in source control. But when I check in I get references to a number of files that I no longer use. How do I remove files from the TFS Source Control repository?

So in the example below, you can see lots of files from different projects that I do not want to see.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean files deleted in TFS are still showing up in your local directory?  Or files that you deleted are still showing in TFS?

Comment: I am finding that there is a lot of stuff I have deleted which still appears when I want to check in my project. The associated checkboxes are unticked by default, but they clutter up my screen.

Comment: Could you expand (perhaps with annotated screen shots?) – it isn't clear where you are having a problem.

Comment: I have put in an image that shows th problem. TFS displays lots of files from different projects, not the one I am working on.

Answer (score 5):

Click on the last icon that looks like a solution (.sln) file icon (last icon on the top vertical row). It's right next to the refresh icon and just above the "Comment" box. That should clear all non-related project files, and only show the files on your current project.

Answer (score 2):

In Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, simply right-click on files and folders and choose "Delete". Then right-click again and choose "Check-in pending changes".

Comment: I delete the item as you suggest, and then I check in the whole project (nothing about "Check in pending changes").
However when I check in, I get a whole list of items on my screen that I do not want to see. How do I get rid f them?

Comment: You may be seeing pending changes from areas outside of your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Destroy those files first, then only those files will get removed from source control.

You can't make any changes in those files - they remain in source control until you destroy them permanently from TFS.

For more info about how to destroy see **TF Destroy** command utility.

Answer (score 1):

The files in your screenshot are (mostly) listed as add - they are not in TFS yet, so deleting them from TFS is not what you want.  Rather you want to ignore them, though that can be tricky: [How to ignore files/directories in TFS for avoiding them to go to central source repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs)