# Change Web.config session value in Global.ascx?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are storing session data in the database, ideally each developer wants a session database on their own pcs, or possibly 1 developer might use inproc, another a mssql connection, another Oracle (if we get it working)

Is this possible? Can you access the session key in code and change it in the application startup? Or is there a file which could be merged with the web.config file that wouldn't get checked in?

Or option C which is easier but which I haven't thought of :-)

thanks

(Edit) Just found this which goes into this in some detail
[developer specific app.config/web.config files in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707749/developer-specific-app-config-web-config-files-in-visual-studio)

(Answer). This came from a mix of Andrew Barber in the comments and the above

(1) In the web.config have this

```
<sessionState configSource="SystemWeb.config" />
```

(2) Make a file called SystemWebDefault.config which holds something like this:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" etc
```

(3) Each developer has to copy the default into a file called SystemWeb.config, changing it to suit themselves. This file should be explicitly ignored in subversion or whatever source control system you use.

(4) The build box needs a copy step

Comment: use windows authentication or have a dev config file - transform that for production. i don't think devs would need sql session data.

Comment: It's to make sure nothing gets added which won't go into the database, i.e. non serializable or similar

Comment: Easiest thing to do is local config files, and local SQL Dev instances for those who want to use database session storage.

Comment: local config files was the answer, add that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Something that might do what you want is NConfig ([NuGet link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NConfig/)).  I've used it on projects to let multiple developers in our team have different connection strings for their local DB copies.  It lets you define a machine specific config file to replace your default config values.  For example you can define a {MachineName}.Custom.config that might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="main" connectionString="data source=(local)\SQLExpress;uid=username;pwd=password;initial catalog=mydb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've never tried it with the session settings, but I can't find anything that says it won't work.