# how do i ignore files in TFS

Tags: tfs

I would like to ignore all generated files from TFS. I am generating *Product.Generated.cs* from *Classes.tt*

I would like to ignore ***.Generated.***   and   ***.ignore;** in TFS

in vs2010 I tried to

right click on source control explorer -> add items to folder

Automatically exclude from Source Control:
Debug;Release;ClientBin;*.pdb;*.obj;*.dll;*.exe;*.res;*.resources;*.cache;*.ilk;*.ncb;*.lce;*.xap;***.Generated.*;*.ignore;**

but everytime I save my Classes.tt file and it creates my XXX.Generated.cs files it tries to add them to TFS

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered NOT ignoring them? What does it hurt?

Comment: technically, since they are generated, I do not consider them to be source. 
pragmatically, I would be happy to include them in source, but it is a pain to have to pre check them out in order to run the templates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore files/directories in tfs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore files/directories in TFS for avoiding them to go to central source repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to put all of the generated code in to a sub folder and then "Cloak" the folder in your workspace. It's not ideal as you would need to do this in every developers workspace