# TFS 2012 Unshelve to different branch -> An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

I need help resolving the following issue:

I am attempting to unshelve code from the source branch onto a target branch.

I am using the following:

- VS2012 RC
- TFS 2012
- VS2012 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt

When I use the command prompt to perform the unshelve operation, the following occurs:

1. Shelveset details dialog gets displayed with list of change files.
2. Click Unshelve button.
3. Observe command prompt output: ***"An item with the same key has already been added."***

I have downloaded ServicePack1 for power tools.
However, I have failed to resolve this issue.

Comment: How many items do you have in the shelveset?  If you try to do them individually do they work or does it choke on one of them?

Comment: I have over 100 items in the shelveset. I tried doing one at a time and it still fails.

Comment: Hi Scott, did each unshelve attempt fail or did it fail on one of the items specifically?  What if you create a new workspace and then try to unshelve into that workspace?

Comment: could you accept an answer, since people the effort in? thx!

Comment: Hi Scott, are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and fixed it when I re-shelved the changeset from the source branch **but chose not to preserve pending changes locally**. After this the migration of the new shelveset ran smoothly.

(I also made sure I'd followed the below steps collected from other answers on this site)

- Use a workspace that encompasses both source and target branches
- Run the command from the folder mapped to the source branch
- Check for quotes around any paths containing spaces
- Deleting the cache in C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache and restarting Visual Studio

Comment: Finally I've seen some delete/edit/rename commands going on. But changes are still not there inside the new branch.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error when using **Visual Studio 2013** and the following command:

```
> tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"$/Root/Solution" /target:"$/Root/Branches/Solution" "The name of my shelveset"
> An item with the same key has already been added
```

**Research**

Here's what I tried to fix the issue:

- Clearing the Cache as per Andrey's answer
- Try running the command from the *Source -> Branch* and *Branch -> Source*
- My workspace already encompassed both source and target branches

**Solution**

Open up your equivalent of the VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt.

1. Check you have Team Foundation Power Tools installed:

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\tfpt
2. Ensure you have 0 **Pending** and **Excluded** changes.
   I had some Excluded changes which were detected but not added and this is what caught me out. Excluded changes should look like this:
   [image]
   **Note:** No *"Detected: XX (adds)"* - should **not** be visible
3. When you run `tf status`, you should see something like the following.
   Either 1 change(s) for the *.tfignore* file or 0 change(s). Anything else will upset the merge.

   > C:\tfs\Root\Solution>tf status
   >   File name Change Local path
   >
   > ---
   >
   > $/Root .tfignore edit   C:\tfs\Root\Solution.tfignore
   >
   > 1 change(s)
4. Ensure you are running the `tfpt` command from the source Solution directory

You should be now be able to successfully merge a shelveset from one branch to another.

**Note on .tfsignore:**
If you have a lot of pending changes that you don't want to undo for whatever reason, then 
a modification to the .tfignore file is ok.
If this is the only file that you have left with changes, it won't brake the merge.
 .tfignore reference => [stackoverflow - How to ignore files/directories in tfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs)

Comment: Very detailed answer, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Yesss! Worked for me too. Key was clearing out the pending changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try to undo all changes on Source and Target branch and then try again...

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete all the files in the following folder and restart VS2012 ([Source](http://henrywrites.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/tfs-vs2012-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added/comment-page-1/#comment-12)):

**C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache**