# using team foundation power tools tfpt "an item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

We are using TFS 2012
I downloaded the TFS Power Tools for vs.net 2013
I am running on windows 7 64bit

I have changed directory into the source branch. Executed the following

tfpt unshelve shelfsetname /migrate /source:$/path1/v1 /target:$/path1/v2

I continually get error
An item with the same key has already been added

I have tried many options, including checking out the shelfset, shelving the set again while not keeping any local changes  etc.

I have removed cache files from paths
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache and
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Any ideas i am at wits end.

I have found other stackoverflow posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978246/tfs-2012-unshelve-to-different-branch-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-b) and tried those options too

Answer (score 2):

You should undo all other pending changes from the root of the branches.
Then only you would be able to migrate the shelveset.