# exclude bin folder from Team Explorer Everywhere

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

How can I exclude the `bin` folder from Check in and Check Out from TFS version control in the [TFS plug-in for Eclipse](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I permanently exclude the bin and obj folders from TFS 2012 checkin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260039/how-do-i-permanently-exclude-the-bin-and-obj-folders-from-tfs-2012-checkin)

Comment: Or also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bin folder should already be ignored by TFS unless everywhere is configured differently. Do possibly mean that the bin folder is already checked in and you don't want to manipulate it any more? If that is the case simply delete the bin from tfs and it will stop prompting you for check out/check in. Bin folders typically are not under source control

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`.tpignore` file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413275%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to ignore files.  The easiest way to add the `bin` directory to your `.tpignore` is to simply right click on the `bin` directory in Package Explorer and select the "Ignore" option in the Team menu.

Comment: Interesting. There are conflicting pages in the docs, claiming that there should be a [`.tpignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413275%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or a [`.tfignore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore) file. 1) which one is it? 2) neither seems to be working in my TFS installation... I wish there was a more complete answer on Stack Overflow somewhere :-)

Comment: @LukasEder it's simple (though perhaps not well documented): server workspaces can use `.tpignore`, local workspaces use `.tfignore`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But neither seems to be considered, when using "compare" or "add items to folder..." actions, right?

Comment: Compare *should* consult the ignore files.  If you explicitly add items to folders, however, that will always override the ignores.

Comment: Compare doesn't seem to consult the ignore files, and with "add items to folder..." I meant that I don't want to see the ignored items as choices in that dialog. I'll have to check what I'm doing wrong... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I added the following to the **.tfignore** file

```
/bin/
/bin/.*
/bin/classes/*
```

I had to include the classes directory explicitly because it continued to appear in the pending changes.