# cannot exclude packages and bin folders from check-in to TFS

Tags: tfs

using VS 2012 and TFS, and I cannot exclude the packages and bin folders from the check-in process, unless I manually exclude them every time. I have created a tfignore file using the VS interface which specifies folders and also file types (e.g. *.nupkg, *.dll etc) but it doesn't work. They still appear in the Team Explorer check in process, and it's causing problems. Please help, it's really annoying me.

Answer (score 1):

is your workspace a local or server one? .tfignore works only on local workspaces.
Have you checked existing SO threads, e.g. [How to ignore files/directories in TFS for avoiding them to go to central source repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs)
If the problem still exists please describe exactly how you add files to tfs (pend add)

Comment: Open workspace dialog, i think running "tf workspace" from cmd will do it.