# How to get TFS to ignore all folders with a certain name

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

Starting with Visual Studio 2015 all solutions create a hidden ".vs" folder with various things under it like applicationhost.config, .suo files, etc...

For informational purposes I'm running TFS 2013 update 4 and I'm not in control of the system so I have no access to upgrade the system.

I know I could go to every solution folder and add a .tfsignore file there with ".vs*" or something similar to ignore the folder but what I'm looking for is how to add a .tfsignore at the root that will ignore all ".vs" folders and the files under them no matter where they are located in the various sub directories.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a `.vs` declaration in a `.tfignore` file that is in the parent folder of all solution files. This will take precedence over lower files.

No wildcards such as `*` are required. Also, `.tfignore` files use backslashes `\` instead of `/`.

Comment: according to microsoft documentation, backslashes are used for non-recursive rules. In the path itself, both slashes do work. Also, I think "This will take precedence over lower files." is also not correct. Files in lower folders overrule the higher .tfignore files. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops&redirectedfrom=MSDN#rules-for-tfignore-files

Answer (score 0):

With TFS Power Tools, you can add Forbidden Patterns Policy, Team->Team Project Settings->Source Control Settings, i.e.`^(.+\.vs$)`

Comment: TFS power tools is not an option, my entire team will not have it installed.  Thanks.

Comment: Check out this then: http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/11/06/excluding-files-from-team-foundation-version-control-using-tfignore-files/

Comment: This does not help as it does not show how to ignore a folder by name recursively.

Answer (score 0):

The effects of the .tfignore file are **recursive.**  Of course, you can  also create .tfignore files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore file in a parent folder.

Moreover, you can also use Forbidden Patterns Policy as TfsAgent mentioned.You will get a policy warn.But the files you forbidden (ex .vs, .dll)  still in included changes.You need to excluded them all by manually.Then undo the pending changes. By note,you need to install [TFS Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)

Comment: So what's the .tfsignore I need to add to get it to ignore all .vs folders and the files under them recursively?  I've not been able to get that to work.

Comment: There are two ways to do it. Way1: add （*.config ，*.suo...）  in your tf.ignore ,put the tf.ignore in the root of your workspace.So it will ignore all  files of the type. Way2:  \xxx.vs  folder this will ignore  all files in the  sub-folder ,you must define  specific  folder name. By the way, there may be some error of tfignore, cause tfs can ignore the new file added in source control, but the type of the file have added in soure control , edit , maybe not igonred. Moreover,TFS power tools only need tfs administrator installed and make the check in policy.

Comment: Way1 does not work, I'm not looking to ignore all .config files, Way2 does not work because I want to ignore all folders named ".vs" recursively, not one occurrence.

Comment: Sorry Aaron , I have double checked in my lab environment. And also can't find some offical document support this feature.It's impossibe to achieve what you want through tf.ignore.Check in policy is a good choice as known.