# tfIgnore does not work for me in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

.tfignore is not working for me in VS2015.

i have few gulp generated minified file and bundle file at WWWROOT folder of ASPNET5 project. I have created the .tfignore file in the solution but it still shows me to add file in the TFS.

how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue with ASP.NET 5 RC1, will be fixed in RC2:

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/289

Comment: I am using RC2 and having the same problem... Is there something I should do or update?