# asp.net core and including shared content files

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a Shared Project project which contains some content files like JSON, etc.

I have a number of ASP.Net core projects and I want to include/share some of these JSON files. Very simple with the "Link to File" option in VS but it's not available in ASP.Net core projects.

I've tried playing with the buildOptions/copyToOutput as follows but this does not seem to be working and no error or warning logged in the build process.

```
"copyToOutput": {
    "include": [ "../Common.Includes/mysettings*.json" ] }
```

Any ideas gratefully accepted?

Thanks

Donal

Answer (score 0):

The `copyToOutput` setting works fine for me (at least in `dotnet 1.0.0-preview3-003171` on Windows). Note however that [copyToOutput is not transitive](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2902) - meaning tath if the files are copied in *project A*, they won't be copied to output in *project B* that references *project A*.

Another method is to use underlying file system and create a symbolic link to the shared file or folder. On Linux it would be:

```sh
> ln -s ../Common.Includes common
```

Windows has a similar (but less commonly used) feature:

```sh
> mklink /J common ..\Common.Includes
```

You can then configure `dotnet` to run it on a specific event:

```json
"scripts": {
    "precompile": "cmd /C mklink /J common ..\\Common.Includes"
}
```

In RC1 there were also events like *'prepare'* or *'prerestore'*, which would be more suitable for this, but for now [they're gone](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3436) and `dotnet` only supports *'precompile'* and *'postcompile'*.

It will be even better to put this command into a separate script along with some logic to check if the link already exists. On windows, I would create `init.ps1` Powershell script:

```powershell
if (!(Test-Path "common")) {
    cmd /C mklink /J "common" "..\Common.Includes"
}
```

Then reference it from *"scripts"*:

```json
"scripts": {
    "precompile": "init.ps1"
}
```

Comment: Hi qbik,

Thanks for taking the time to put together such a consise answer.
I have the Preview 2 Sdk and tools installed - my version is 1.0.0-preview2-003121. And I'm running from within VS2015.

My source control system is VSTS/TFS and from what I've read I dont think symbolic links and TFS work perfect together.

So that leaves some form of copy process via scripts.

I might wait until v1 of the tools to see if it works in that and if not go the script approach.

Thanks

Donal

Comment: @DonalMcWeeney: `copyToOutput` works also in `1.0.0-preview2-003121` (I checked). Note however that those files will be copied to *bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0* directory (or something similar, depending on project settings), so you won't see them in VS.

Comment: As of the script approach: I recommend adding the symlink (*common* directory in the answer above) to ignored files in Version Control, so it won't get checked-in (in git it would be an entry in *.gitignore*, I'm not sure how to [ignore directory in TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source)). This way you avoid duplication in VCS and it should still work on other developers' machines - the symlink will be automatically recreated on build.