# dotnet publish, contentFiles, and transitive nuget dependencies

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-core

Is it possible for `dotnet publish` to copy `contentFiles` to output from a transitive package dependencies?

In this scenario, I have three projects:

1. Content, which has a `nuspec` containing:

```html
<contentFiles>
  <files include="any/any/someContent.txt" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false"/>
</contentFiles>
```

2. Lib, which has a `PackageReference` to Content nuget
3. ConsoleApp, which has a `PackageReference` to Lib nuget

The Lib project shows the contentFiles in the project explorer and copies to output on build, but the ConsoleApp project does neither.

I need `dotnet publish ConsoleApp.csproj` to include `someContent.txt` from the Content nuget in the publish output.

Somewhat related posts for context:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38518024/5915331
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899966/5915331

Answer (score 6):

`contentFiles` are Private Assets by default. You need to change the `PrivateAssets` metadata in the reference from `Lib` to `Content`, so that it doesn't include `contentFiles`, like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="...">
    <PrivateAssets>analyzers;build</PrivateAssets>
</ProjectReference>
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets

Comment: Would this be helpful in this situation?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/65051835/227436 I tried to implement the settings, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: I think it should. Are you changing `PrivateAssets` in the reference from `DLaB.Xrm.Source` to `DLaB.Common.Source`?

Comment: No.  I'm only including content

Comment: In the `DLaB.Xrm.Source` project, you should change the reference to `DLaB.Common.Source`, like this: `<ProjectReference Include="path/to/DLaB.Common.Source.csproj" PrivateAssets="analyzers;build" />`.

Comment: My DLaB.Xrm.Source is actually a .Net project, not a dotnetcore

Comment: So I guess you are using nuspec, right? In that case, I compared the nuspec outputs, and I believe the equivalent there would be replacing `exclude="Build,Analyzers"` with `include="Runtime,Compile,Native,ContentFiles,BuildTransitive"`.