# Remove a solution directory from source control

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I am using Visual Studio Team Services (Visual Studio Online) w/ TFVC for source control. My MVC application has a directory in the wwwroot called uploads (where I am doing testing to upload files).

I do not want this folder to be part of source control at all. How do I exclude it from source control completely?

Comment: Here's some info on ignoring folders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`.tfignore`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#tfignore) file to your project and delete the folder from source control.