# tfignore in ASP.NET Core Project VS 2015 Update 3 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, asp.net-core, tfvc

We have a .tfignore file in our ASP.NET Core project at the root level.  We have an Angular TS application being generated to a wwwroot\app folder which we don't want added to tfs for obvious reasons.  The problem is every time we build green plus icons appear by all the files and our .tfignore file is have no effect.

Could someone please help identify what's going on?  Content of our tsconfig is as follows -

wwwroot\app

We have tried all the following

\wwwroot\app
wwwroot\app\
wwwroot\app*.*

As well as moving the tfignore to the solution level nothing works.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using local workspaces or server workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

This issue should has been fixed in VS 2015 Update 3: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/18

I've also tested a ASP.NET Core project in VS2015.3, .tfignore works as expected.

If you put the .tfignore in the root of the net core project with the paths:
wwwroot\app, but it is still in pending changes. Try to delete the entire solution from the disk, then download again from TFS as @airomero did in the link.

Adding a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cece I'll give  that a go.

Comment: Still not working Cece.  We are using TFS 2010 could this be this issue?

Comment: @user2997206, yes, I think so, as only when you add ignored files to folders that are mapped in a local workspace, they do not appear in the Pending Changes page in Team Explorer. But TFS 2010 doesn't support local workspace. This feature exists in TFS 2012 and later version.

Comment: This worked for me. It didn't initally go away from the team explorer view, but I had it 'undo' (ie remove) the files that were being added. After that it began ignoring them.
For those who need it I found some decent instructions on this answer for using tfignore files.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source#21102343