# Exclude a folder from checkin TFS online

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

i am using visualstudio.com as TFS online and have created my code repo there.

In my project there is folder that comprises several subfolders and eachsub folder has several images (the total of all images is like 6000).

When i check-in my code I do not want the root folder (i.e. the parent folder of image subfolders) and its content to be checkedin?

I tried online for some answers but cannot find anything accurate.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be beneficial to update your question to state if you are using Git or TFVC, both of which are supported in TFS 2015 and up...

Answer (score 18):

You can configure which kinds of files are ignored by placing text file called `.tfignore` in the folder where you want rules to apply. The effects of the `.tfignore` file are **recursive**. However, you can create `.tfignore` files in sub-folders to override the effects of a .tfignore file in a parent folder.

To create the file, the easiest way is  using the **auto automatically generated .tfignore file**, follow below steps:

1. In the Pending Changes page, in the Excluded Changes section, choose
   the Detected changes link.

[image: pending changes, Detected changes link , which counts the number of adds, in this case 50003 add(s) (I have a busy directory clearly!)]

The Promote Candidate Changes dialog box appears.

2. Select a file, open its context menu, and choose Ignore this local
   item, Ignore by extension, Ignore by file name, or Ignore by folder.

[image: the promote candidate changes dialog opens. right-clicking an item in its list includes options like "Ignore by extension *.js"]

3. Choose OK or Cancel to close the Promote Candidate Changes dialog
           box.
4. A .tfignore file appears in the Included Changes section of the
       Pending Changes page. You can open this file and modify it to meet
      your needs.

[image: the .tfignore is automatically created by Visual Studio and appears in pending changes with the "add" notation, suggesting you will commit it]

More info please check the *Customize which files are ignored by version control* from MSDN Link:[Add files to the server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

There's an easy way to do it, i.e. via the **.tfignore** file. Go to the root folder of your and tfs checkin and put following content in the .tfignore file. If the file is not there create it.

**.tfignore**

```
<rootfoldername>
```

**Method 2:**

To exclude a file from source control

1. In Visual Studio, open Solution Explorer and select the file to
   exclude.
2. On the File menu, click Source Control, then click Exclude
   from Source Control.
3. When you are ready to place the file under
   source control, you can access the File menu and click Source
   Control, then uncheck Exclude from Source Control.

Edit:
This question is a possible duplicate of 
[How to ignore files/directories in TFS for avoiding them to go to central source repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source)

Edit: 
Changed the file name to .tfignore

Comment: For method 2, it would have to applied to each file and i have 6000 of them, so not feasible.

Comment: for method 1, please could state clearly, where is this file?

Comment: The file is called `.tfignore`, not `.tfsignore`

Comment: For method 1 the file has to be in the root checkin directory