# TFS - Filter Specific File Types from Changeset Details

Tags: typescript, tfs, version-control, sass

We use Team Foundation Server (TFS) for source control.

In our solution we use TypeScript and SASS to create JavaScript and CSS files respectively.  Although .js and .css files are included in our source control (since they are ultimately the files put into production), any 'changes' occur to the corresponding .ts and .scss files.

However, when reviewing a changeset in TFS, all of the .js and .css files are included along with the .ts and .scss files.  Often times a simple change in a few .ts/.scss files can lead to a large number of changes in .js/.css files - crowding the changeset details.

Is there any way to filter which file types are displayed in a changeset so that it is easier to review what has 'actually' changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source

Answer (score 0):

Those JavaScript and CSS files are build artifacts. You shouldn't put them into source control -- let your build system build them as necessary, the same way your developers do.

You can ignore files or folders via `.tfignore` files for TFVC or via `.gitignore` files for Git.