# Visual Studio include generated javascript to the source control

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, tfs, visual-studio-2017

After Visual Studio updated from 15.7.x to 15.8.1, VS puts generated Javascript files from Typescript to the TFS.

Is there a way how to not include them? I can manually move them to exclude changes, but I would rather VS to not to add these files to Included Changes. In the previous version of VS, it generated javascript files but it didn't put them under source control (this is preferred behavior).

Thank you,
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

You may use tfignore to ignore files from showing up on the pending.

Make sure you first remove them from your repo and to correctly ignore them in the file.

Analytical details about how to do that can be found at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source) answer