# TFS/Azure Devops NOT Ignore .pubxml Files

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, tfignore

I have a solution with APIs and injectable services in multiple separate projects on TFS/Azure.

Although I excluded all `Properties/PublishProfiles/XXX.pubxml` files from Solution Explorer, they are still in the list that waiting for check-in:

[image: TFS]

Then I tried to add ***.pubxml** and **.pubxml** extension manually to `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\[X.X]\Configuration\VersionControl\LocalItemExclusions.config` but no chance.

I created `tfignore` file follow instruction both on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#tfignore) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40409464/5277883) (thanks to @Lennart) but nothing changed. It's still on the **Pending Changes** list.

Any other solution for ignoring file extensions on **TFS/Azure**? Especially I'm looking for ignoring *.pubxml* extension, obviously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore files/directories in TFS for avoiding them to go to central source repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source)

Comment: I followed to instruction on the link you sent me and also this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#tfignore). But they didn't solved the problem: `.pubxml` is still on the **Pending Changes** list. @Lennart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude files from Solution Explorer doesn't mean you exclude them from source control, you just exclude them from the solution explorer. You could exclude right click the file in pending changes, and then click **Exclude**:

[image]

Comment: Of course I'm excluding it. But why should I press exclude every time I try to check-in? I want it to not show me at all on this **Pending Changes** part. See [this](https://i.ibb.co/NrwZ5Lj/pending.png) for details please.

Comment: If you add or remove a file outside Visual Studio, for example, in Windows Explorer , the Detected changes link appears in the Excluded Changes section. If you don't want to version control the .pubxml file, you could delete it from version control.