# TFS Ignoring Resx Files by default

Tags: tfs, tfvc

My work keeps employee equipment updated regularly and I recently received a new development laptop with Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022 installed.  Prior to that, I was using a PC with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

To my knowledge, these are the **only** environmental factors that have changed.  But since then, when I add a Resource file (resx) to my project, it is not automatically added to source control under TFS.  Other types of files continue to behave as expected.

I've looked all over stack overflow for why this might have started happening but cannot find a cause.  A ".tfignore" file doesn't exist on my system and shouldn't have to exist for these types of files to be added to source control by default.  Is there a configuration somewhere on the Team Foundation Server that controls what files are ignored by default that someone may have changed?  Is my SO Search Fu just failing me and I haven't found the right article?

To add further information, the file type is listed here under the Team Explorer settings:
[image]

I have also examined what I can inside the Team Foundation Server Administrator Console and can't find any settings options there that might control this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC for version control?

Comment: It's a bit old school - pre-DevOps and all that.  It's literally an on-premise TFS Server:
**Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**
Version 16.131.28226.3

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. TFS supports both Git and TFVC for version control.

Comment: Since this is an older version that, as near as I can tell, doesn't even know Git exists, we'll go with TFVC.

Comment: For what it's worth, you're using TFS 2018 which definitely supports Git.

Comment: you could manage a file called '.tfignore', which acts likes .gitignore, indicating which files will be ignored / included. to include a file that is excluded by default you can put '!*.<fileextention>' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922798/how-to-ignore-files-directories-in-tfs-for-avoiding-them-to-go-to-central-source